# Should I make the method virtual or abstract?

Tags: c#, .net, class-design

I have an abstract class that does its own internal validation. It has another method that allows subclasses to do additional validation checks. Currently, I've made the method `abstract`.

```
protected abstract bool ValidateFurther();
```

However, I'm seeing quite a number of subclasses being forced to override it just to return `true`. I'm considering to make the method `virtual`.

```
protected virtual bool ValidateFurther() => true;
```

Is it bad to assume that validation is going to be fine in the abstract class? I'm worried that subclasses may not notice it and ended up not overriding it even when it is needed. Which is the more suitable approach here?

Comment: leave it abstract if you want to force a derived class to implement something

Comment: We can't really answer this without more context

Answer (score 1):

You could add another layer into your design.

```
public abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract bool ValidateFurther();
}

public abstract class BaseWithValidation : Base
{
    protected override bool ValidateFurther() => true;
}
```

If a significant subset of your inherited classes should just return true you can use `BaseWithValidation` to avoid having to repeat the code everywhere; for anything else use `Base`.

Comment: It might be better to name it `BaseWithNoFurtherValidation`

Comment: Alternatively, an `IFurtherValidatable`-Interface might be a solution.

Comment: It makes no sense for a "base without validation" class to have a `Validate` method.

Answer (score 0):

- `abstract` method means you just want to define the behavior to be followed, and let sub classes do the implementation.
- `virtual` method means you defined an method with initial implementation, but allow to be override.

So maybe you can explain you context more, then we can discuss it!

Answer (score 0):

It's okay to make the method `virtual` and define a default implementation returning `true`.

```
protected virtual bool ValidateFurther() => true;
```

The difference between `abstract` and `virtual` is that that abstract methods defines only the signature of a method and the implementation is left to be implemented by the derived classes(similar to an interface). All child classes are required to implement the logic of an abstract method. You can see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract) for more details.

`Virtual` on the other hand requires you to implement the logic and if needed you can `override` that method to add/extend the logic. And because you have default logic your child/derived classes are not required to `override` it. You can see the [documnetation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) for more details.

Basically it is okay to implement the method as `virtual` and `return true;` by default.

FYI: From C# 8 you can have default implementations in the interfaces [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-interface-methods-in-c-sharp-8-0/)

Answer (score 0):

### The short answer

If this class' (and all of its derived class') purpose does not always necessitate validation, then you should go with `virtual`, otherwise `abstract`.

In other words, is validation a cornerstone of this class' purpose? (yes = abstract, no = virtual)

I suspect that `virtual` is the better approach here, but not for the reason you're thinking it is. The rest of this answer elaborates on why your reasoning isn't the deciding factor here, and what actually is the deciding factor.

---

### Your reasoning

> I'm seeing quite a number of subclasses being forced to override it just to return true.

I suspect you're succumbing to the programmer's reflex: *"I see this repeated and must write code to avoid this repetition!"*

While that is generally a good approach, it can also be misapplied when you start applying this to things that *happen to be* the same rather than expressing the same functional purpose.

The example I tend to use to address that point is the following:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeJob
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

There is definitely value to abstracting the `CreatedOn` property, as these entities are both audited data entities. The `CreatedOn` property is part of that audited entity, and its existence in both `Book` and `EmployeeJob` stems from these classes both being audited entities.

If a change is made to audited entities (e.g. they no longer track creation date), then that change needs to automatically persist to all audited entities. When you use shared logic, that automatically happens.

But does `Title` need to be abstracted into a shared logic? No. There is no functional overlap here. Yes, these properties have the same name and type, but they share no common logic whatsoever. They just **happen to be** equal to each other right now, but they are not tied to one another.

If a change is made to one `Title` property (e.g. it now becomes a `Guid` FK to a table of job titles), that change doesn't automatically reflect on the other (e.g. a book title would still just be a string). Implementing these `Title` properties using shared logic would actually cause a problem down the line instead of solve one.

In short: sometimes programmers seek more patterns than they need. Or if you allow me to [quote Jurassic Park](https://i.imgflip.com/1gn0wt.jpg)...

---

### The deciding factor

> I'm considering to make the method virtual.

Whether you make it abstract or virtual depends on one specific considerations (not DRY, as addressed above): Do you wish to provide a default implementation, or would you prefer to enforce that every consumer (i.e. derived class) evaluate the implementation of this method for themselves?

Neither of these are objectively better than the other, it's a matter of which fits best for you current scenario.

> I'm seeing quite a number of subclasses being forced to override it just to return true.

I infer from this that you're essentially skipping validation in these classes, so in this case I would opt for the `virtual` approach since this class' (and all of its derived class') purpose does not always necessitate validation (again, that is my interpretation based on your explanation).

In other words, is validation a cornerstone of this class' purpose? (yes = abstract, no = virtual). You didn't specify your class or its purpose so I can't make that final call.